# Wordpress Widget: Don't display $before_title and $after_title if title is empty

Tags: wordpress, widget

If the wordpress widget title is blank or empty, then don't display the $before_title and $after_title wrapping the title.

Right now if the title is empty, you can end up with . If there are margins set for h2.widgettitle then you end up with blank space.

In reality, $before_title and $after_title shouldn't show up at all if there is no widget title.

I can work around it by changing the CSS #mytheme .widgettitle style, but one shouldn't have to change the stylesheet based on content.

Comment: Do you need some particular code help, or are you just kind of complaining about this?

Comment: I need a code to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should help get rid of the space. I am not too sure if this will work, but try adding it to your functions.php instead of your widget file to apply to all your widgets.

```
function custom_widget_title($title) {
$title = trim($title);
return $title;
}
add_filter('widget_title', 'custom_widget_title');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a widget, then replace the lines in your widget() method that shows the Title with the following code.

```
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
  echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
}
```

If you want to modify the title for existing/default widgets, then I would recommend you to define your custom widgets that extend the existing widgets.

Comment: Have tested something does not work the way you want. I have 20 widgets. I would like to apply to everyone. Without nescessidade to change everything.

Comment: <blink>add_filter('widget_title','et_widget_force_title');
function et_widget_force_title( $title ){ 
 #add an empty title for widgets ( otherwise it might break the sidebar layout )
 if ( $title == '' ) $title = ' ';
 
 return $title;
}'
</blink>